# Random Reads and Scans inside the same HBase cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-yarn

We have a situation where we host data for:

- MapReduce/Spark jobs (disk accessed by seq. reads)
- Random reads.
  (disk accessed by seeks)

All inside the same cluster/table.

With YARN we can manage resources like CPU and RAM, but during intensive scans HDD can become a bottleneck and can slow down random read performance. How to manage that resource

How this kind of situations are being handled in general?

Answer (score 0):

Since mapreduce generally does not require live data, people often make a backup of hbase table and run mapreduce on backup data table. Or do a snapshot of table and run mp. on it.